# XSLT: Check if tag exists on the outputted XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

How can I check if a tag exists using xslt?
The difference being that i want to check the XML that I am creating (not the input XML).

Kinda like `<xsl:when test="phone">` but for the output instead.

Comment: When using XSLT you perform selection and tests on the input document. You drive with the transform the input to create the output. Your question has not much sense to me unless you want test the existince of an element in a node-set variable. In that case, anyway, you would use the same way as you use to check input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result tree of a stylesheet is write-only. If you want to read it, you can do that from another transformation - pipelines of transformations are a useful design pattern. But you haven't said what problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you chain two stylesheets where the second takes the result from the first as its input or unless you store a result in a variable with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="temp-result">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
<xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="$temp-result//phone">
  <xsl:copy-of select="$temp-result"/>
</xsl:if>
```

I don't think there is a way. Note that above approach with a variable works that way with XSLT 2.0, with 1.0 you would need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` in `test="exsl:node-set($temp-result)//phone"`.

A third option might exist with schema-aware XSLT 2.0 by validating a result against a schema, that way you could ensure the result is an instance of a schema.